# MPI-3 RMA one sided communication segmentation fault on fetch_and_op

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, mpi

I want to build a counter via MPI3-RMA and wrote this code, in which variable a is incremented by every but the first rank:

```
PROGRAM fetchAndOpTest
     USE mpi 
     IMPLICIT NONE
     INTEGER, PARAMETER     :: masterRank   = 0 
     INTEGER, PARAMETER     :: ONE          = 1 
     INTEGER                :: myRank       = 0 
     INTEGER                :: numProcs     = 1 
     INTEGER                :: win, ierror
     INTEGER                :: a
     INTEGER (KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) &
                             :: lowerbound, sizeofint

     CALL MPI_INIT(ierror)
     CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myRank,ierror)
     CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,numProcs, ierror)
     CALL MPI_TYPE_GET_EXTENT(MPI_INTEGER, lowerbound,sizeofint, ierror)
     CALL MPI_WIN_CREATE(a,sizeofint,sizeofint,MPI_INFO_NULL,MPI_COMM_WORLD,win,ierror)

     a = 0 
     WRITE(*,*) "Rank ",myRank,"meldet a = ",a

     CALL MPI_WIN_FENCE(0,win,ierror)
     IF(myRank .NE. masterRank) THEN
        CALL MPI_Fetch_and_op(ONE,a,MPI_INTEGER,masterRank,0, MPI_SUM,win,ierror)
     END IF
     CALL MPI_WIN_FENCE(0,win,ierror)

     WRITE(*,*) "Rank ",myRank,"meldet a = ",a              
     CALL MPI_WIN_FREE(win,ierror)
     CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)   
  END PROGRAM fetchAndOpTest
```

So on the master rank 0 should be `a == numProcs-1` after the fetch_and_op-operation. But the line `CALL MPI_Fetch_and_op(ONE,a,MPI_INTEGER, masterRank,0, MPI_SUM,win,ierror)` leads to a segmentation fault:

```
> mpirun -np 2 ./fetchAndOpTestF90.x 
Rank            0 meldet a =            0
Rank            1 meldet a =            0
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
[...]
```

Its hard to find RMA example code for Fortran but I tried to adept the code from https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/593485 to solve my problem. Same problem as before.

Used compiler: mpiifort

Comment: I am not familiar with `MPI_Fetch_and_op` but I am pretty sure that you must not use a named constant as the first arg. Declare a variable and assign it the value of the named constant `ONE`, then use that variable instead of the named constant.

Comment: I removed all PARAMETER, still the same seg-fault

Comment: @innoSPG, the first argument of `MPI_Fetch_and_op` is `INTENT(IN)` and therefore constants are perfectly acceptable as actual arguments.

Comment: You are calling MPI with wrong types of actual arguments. Try with `CALL MPI_WIN_CREATE(..., sizeofint, INT(sizeofint), ...)` and `CALL MPI_Fetch_and_op(..., 0_MPI_ADDRESS_KIND, ...)`.

Comment: That solved the segFault, great! But why do I not need to change the type of `win` to `TYPE(MPI_WIN)` instead of `INTEGER`? If I try so, the compiler throws `The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument` for `CALL MPI_WIN_FENCE(0,win,ierror)`...

Comment: Typed MPI handles are part of the `use mpi_f08` interface. The `use mpi` interface uses `INTEGER` to represent the handles. That's why the latter should be considered obsolete and should not be used for newly developed programs.